# Почему меняется кодировка PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с не понятной для меня проблемой:
Я делаю POST запрос на сервер к файлу test.php с двумя параметрами : info1, info2
info1 - это данные для MySQL
info2 - просто string с русскими буквами = "Привет"
Сам файл test.php

```
<?php
require_once('data.php');
require 'main_info.php';
$site= $_POST['info1']; //site
$var1 = $_POST['info2']; //var1
if (!empty($site))
{   
  $link = mysql_connect($MySQL_hostname,$MySQL_username,$MySQL_password);
  mysql_select_db($MySQL_databasename);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $MySQL_table  WHERE `Site` = '$site'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $var2 = $row['Title'];
  echo $var1 .";" .$var2;
}
else
{
  echo "ERR";
}
?>
```

$row['Title'] - в таблице эта ячейка занята текстом "Здарова".
И в итоге у меня ответ от этого файла идет такой:
**РџСЂРёРІРµС‚;Здарова**.
Но если вместо `echo $var1 .";" .$var2;` будет `echo $var1;` то ответ:
**Привет** .
В чем тут проблема? Как сделать, чтоб ответ приходил в нормальной кодировке , или что это вообще такое?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, каждая HTML страница имеет свою кодировку отображения текста (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`).
Вот-вторых, база данных тоже имеет свою кодировку (`SET names 'UTF-8';`). И вот если первое со вторым не совпадают, то тут начинаются проблемы